# What is this pop up on hover and how to turn it off?

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to Android Studio and does not know more about it so here is the question to the experts. I am using studio for Flutter development.

What is this small popup (with text "+{..}{SliverToBoxAdapter} SliverToBoxAdapter") which displays the TYPE of the symbol and how should i turn it off in android studio ?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot seems to be relevant here, since the question isn't about the code itself. It's about a feature of Android Studio (or by an installed plugin).

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the same already. Is it not visible ? @Tim Klingeleers

Comment: Seems like the other commenter removed his comment in which he stated that code should be in a code block instead of a screenshot. So that makes my comment irrelevant.